# How can I solve this cannot ImportError: cannot import name in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

Repository for reference --> https://github.com/SavSanta/bluinfo

So, Im trying to import a class `BDROM` I made in the file called `bluinfo.py`. (line 27)

By adding the line `from bluinfo import BDROM` to the bluinfo-gui.py (line 8)

I am receiving `ImportError: cannot import name 'BDROM'`

I can not figure out how to get this badboy to work. Other posts state it may be related to PYTHONPATH (despite similar imports have been working in other parts of the program and all files are in the same directory).

---

I've tried to alter the import statement in the following ways to no success:

1. *from .bluinfo import BDROM*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.bluinfo'; '__main__' is not a package
```

2. *from ..bluinfo import BDROM*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

3. Creating an **init**.py file (which I believe I read is unnecessary in python3.x) and trying the import

```
$dev:/tmp/blue/bluinfo$ touch __init__.py
$dev:/tmp/blue/bluinfo$ python3 bluinfo-gui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bluinfo-gui.py", line 8, in <module>
    from bluinfo import BDROM
  File "/tmp/blue/bluinfo/bluinfo.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ts_scanner as ScanTask
  File "/tmp/blue/bluinfo/ts_scanner.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ts_streamtypeclass
  File "/tmp/blue/bluinfo/ts_streamtypeclass.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bluinfo import BDROM
ImportError: cannot import name 'BDROM'
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/SavSanta/bluinfo/blob/master/bluinfo.git 
404 please fix

Comment: I put a better link.

Comment: I find error in 
# import ts_scanner as ScanTask

Comment: The issue is resolved. The issue was the import in `ts_streamtypeclass.py` causing circular importing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your third attempt you have a circular import. Restructure your code to avoid that.

For example, you might be able to eliminate one of these imports, and you will get rid of the circular dependency.

```
  File "/tmp/blue/bluinfo/bluinfo.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ts_scanner as ScanTask

  File "/tmp/blue/bluinfo/ts_streamtypeclass.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bluinfo import BDROM
```

PS: Since you have a file called `blueinfo.py` in a directory called `blueinfo`, the statement `import blueinfo` might mean either the package (directory) or the module (file). You could consider renaming the files inside the blueinfo directory to something more descriptive, to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: So the circular import breaking happens the ` File "/tmp/blue/bluinfo/ts_streamtypeclass.py", line 3, in <module> from bluinfo import BDROM` which makes sense because it was the most recent change where I import it again in order to use a static method defined on BDROM class. Seems to be no way around it other than to reimplement the method in the file. So I guess I'll go with that. Thanks

Comment: rename doesn't help

Comment: Naming things properly makes the code easier to understand for humans. In this case, the use of the same name for a module and a package makes it harder to understand what happens when Python's import resolution doesn't give the result we expect. It doesn't solve the bug here, but it might help avoid similar bugs in the future.